# Python ctypes import error in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, ctypes, importerror

I get the following error when importing `ctypes`, but only inside my virtual environment (Python 3.4).

```
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ImportError: /home/user/Code/Python/venvs/main/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceback_Add
```

pip freeze of the virtualenv:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.0
blessings==1.6
Django==1.8.4
image==1.4.1
Pillow==2.9.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

How do I fix this? It works on the main python 3.4 interpreter...

Comment: In 3.4.3 the old `_ctypes_add_traceback` was moved to the internal API, `_PyTraceback_Add` (see [issue 22462](http://bugs.python.org/issue22462)). It appears that somehow you're using a 3.4.3+ build of the `_ctypes` extension module with an older version of Python 3.4.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @eryksun ! It works now :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [eryksun described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223713/python-ctypes-import-error-in-virtualenv#comment54266298_33223713), the issue seems to be related to a [known bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22462) in the 3.4.* versions of Python. I managed to solve it in Ubuntu 14.04 by upgrading to Python 3.5 following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/install-python-3-5-on-vivid-using-apt-get/682875#682875):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5 python3.5-dev python3.5-venv
# create a python3.5 virtualenv
python3.5 -m venv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
python -c 'import ctypes' # throws no errors as opposed to before
```

The proper solution where you don't depend on 3rd party PPAs would be to upgrade to an OS version with a newer Python version :)

Comment: im with python v3.6 still with same problem

Answer (score 4):

Try destroying and recreating your virtual environment. In my case, I had created the virtual environment before installing dependancies/minor upgrade and even though the virtual env had symlinks to the newer files, a copy of the older minor version interpreter was used.